# Why am I getting an Uncaught exception error in my PayPal IPN Listener with PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have never done anything with PayPal IPN listeners or cURL in general so I am not sure exactly what I am doing.  I am trying to set up my IPN listener with PHP so I can test it locally.  I am getting the error `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL error: [0] '`  I am using the code from paypal's [github](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php)  What am I doing wrong?  I am using CodeIgniter 2

The error occurs on this line of code from ipnlistener.php:

```
throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
```

This is my controller method:

```
function ipnlistener(){
    $this->load->library('ipnlistener');
    $this->ipnlistener->useSandbox();
    if($this->ipnlistener->verifyIPN()){
        show_error("IPN Verified.");            
    } else {
        show_error("IPN Failed.");
    }
}
```

Here is the form that sends the data:

```
                        <form action="<?=site_url('members/billing/ipnlistener');?>" method="post" target="_new">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HLZ8PPFTUK6X6">
                                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PHP">
                                <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Billing Cycle</label>
                                    <select name="os0">
                                        <option value="Monthly">Monthly : P250.00 PHP - monthly</option>
                                        <option value="Yearly">Yearly : P2,500.00 PHP - yearly</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

ipnlistener.php

```
<?php
class ipnlistener
{
    /**
     * @var bool $use_sandbox     Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used.
     */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /**
     * @var bool $use_local_certs Indicates if the local certificates are used.
     */
    private $use_local_certs = true;
    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';
    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }
    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }
        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is curl enabled?

Comment: Yes, curl is enabled.